# subplots based on records of two different pandas DataFrames ( with same structure) using Seaborn or Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I have two DataFrames like below. Both have the same structure (columns names and index) but different values. DataFrame 1 is observed values and DataFrame 2 is predicted. I wanted to draw a single figure using subplots each representing one of the columns, Y- axis to be the values from both dataframes ( two different lines) and X-axis the index.

I know that I am supposed to post sample codes of my work but it seems they are all wrong, that is why I am not sharing my sample code. I really want to use something like the sns.FacetGrid of seaborn as the plots have higher qualities.

```
    08FB006 08FC001 08FC003 08FC005 08GD004
----------------------------------------------
0   253      872    256      11.80    2660
1   250      850    255      10.60    2510
2   246      850    241      10.30    2130
3   241      827    235      9.32     1970
4   241      821    229      9.17     1900
5   232      819    228      8.93     1840
6   231      818    225      8.05     1710
7   234      817    225      7.90     1610
8   210      817    224      7.60     1590
9   200      816    221      7.53     1590
10  199      810    219      7.41     1550
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify below code according to your needs -

```
actual = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5, 8, 9, 6, 7, 2],
                       'b': [89, 22, 44, 6, 44, 1]})
predicted = pd.DataFrame({'a': [7, 2, 13, 18, 20, 2],
                       'b': [9, 20, 4, 16, 40, 11]})

# Creating a tidy-dataframe to input under seaborn
merged = pd.concat([pd.melt(actual), pd.melt(predicted)]).reset_index()
merged['category'] = ''
merged.loc[:len(actual)*2,'category'] = 'actual'
merged.loc[len(actual)*2:,'category'] = 'predicted'

g = sns.FacetGrid(merged, col="category", hue="variable")
g.map(plt.plot, "index", "value", alpha=.7)
g.add_legend();
```

[image: plt]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I need the category to be column names, not the DataFrames. its like I want both "a" from actual and predicted to be in the same subplot with "a" as category and blue line predicted orange as actual.

Comment: If I get you, then you should just interchange `col` and `hue` values like `g = sns.FacetGrid(merged, hue="category", col="variable")`

Comment: this code works but the pandas.melt changes the index ... I need to keep the index as x-axis - for each column, there is 50 index that should be kept, however, this code will make the index go up to 4000 because it resets the index and does not keep the original index values- you may check your graphs for "b" dataframe indices are from 5-10 which is wrong